# How does DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer work with batch consumer?

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am trying to understand how DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer works in case of batch consumer. Most of the examples in documentation I can see are that of single record consumers.

I want to implement a retry logic for a batch consumer. If the retries also fail after a threshold (let's say 3 times), then the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer should publish the message to a Dead Letter Topic. Order does not matter for my use case.

I am not sure whether:

The DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer will publish the failed record to DLT, and the rest of the records in the batch will be processed by the consumer.

Or

The DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer will publish the failed record as well as the entire batch (including good messages) to DLT.

```
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
       
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setBatchListener(true);
        
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate);
        RecoveringBatchErrorHandler recoveringBatchErrorHandler = new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer,new FixedBackOff(1000L, 3L));

        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setBatchErrorHandler(recoveringBatchErrorHandler);

        return concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` (`DefaultErrorHandler` in version 2.8 and later), the listener must throw a `BatchListenerFailedException`; this tells the error handler where, in the batch, the error occurred.

Records prior to that one will have their offsets committed; the failed record (and subsequent records in the batch) are retried; when retries are exhausted, the failed record is sent to the DLT and the remaining records are retries.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh

for versions before 2.8.